# Having some issues getting powershell to show me when the value it check with AD can't be found

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

So I have a powershell command where I give it a CSV of emails and I tell it to check out our AD server and return the usernames associated with the email. The issue I'm having is when I feed it a list of emails some of the email are wrong but the exported CSV doesn't have which emails it couldn't match to a username.

Here's the powershell line I'm running.

```
Import-CSV -Path C:\Users\PathToCSV |
    ForEach-Object {Get-ADUser -Filter "UPN -eq '$($_.email)'" -server SERVER NAME -Properties *} |
    select SamAccountName | Export-CSV C:\FilePathOfExportInCSV -NoTypeInformation
```

So this will tell me what emails have Username in our AD server but I also want to know what emails it wasn't able to match. Is what I'm asking doable within powershell ?

Comment: yes, it is doable. you need to add a step in your `ForEach-Object` to handle that. when you use a `-Filter`, there will not be an error, just an empty return. add a check for that.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. I've been looking around but can't find what i think you're talking about I'm not super familiar with powershell so when you say add a check for that how do you suggest I do that.

Comment: the simplest is to assign the `Get-ADUser` call to a $Var and then check to see if it has anything in it. [*grin*]